# ruby/bash: How do I download a large file with using the "If-Range" and "Range" headers?

Tags: ruby, http, curl

I've been trying to use mechanize to download mp3 files, but the server always returns a 404.

Looking at the headers my browser sends (checked on Chrome and FF), I noticed that the `If-Range` and `Range` headers are used to initiate a successful download, so I'm guessing the server is rejecting any request that doesn't specify them.

What is the right way to download files in this way, using ruby (`Net::HTTP`) or bash (`curl` or `wget`)?

Answer (score 0):

404 is file not found. Are you sure your URL is correct? If it is correct then you should be able to use wget <full url and file name> to test it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the URL. Like I said, it doesn't work with a simple HTTP request, as it seems that the server rejects it unless you use the specified headers.